# Html5 Barchart - Bar height issues

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a barchart that is made up of rectangles.

I call a function that creates a rectangle and adds it to the html 5 canvas. The container that the rectangles get painted on has a height. Lets say this height is 200

```
AddRectangle(xPos,yPos,height,width)
```

So I call it like

```
AddRectangle(0,0,100,20)
AddRectangle(30,0,110,20)
AddRectangle(60,0,120,20)
AddRectangle(90,0,150,20)
```

This will add the rectangles no problem. The issue I have is what if the rectangles are very small in height ie

```
AddRectangle(0,0,1,20)
AddRectangle(30,0,4,20)
AddRectangle(60,0,5,20)
AddRectangle(90,0,6,20)
```

Then they will appear tiny and hard to distinguish between which is the highest value.
Is there some formula i could use to get the height of the rectangles in proportion to the height of the rectangle container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the formula. I had to work out the percentages of the numbers from the max number. the max number being 100%

Work out the higest number

```
        for (var i=0; i<frequincies.length; i++) {
            if (parseInt(frequincies[i]) > parseInt(maxValue)) maxValue = frequincies[i];
        }
```

Get the percentages of the other numbers from the highest number

```
for (var i=0; i<frequincies.length; i++) {
    var percentage = (parseInt(frequincies[i])) / maxValue;
    percentages.push(percentage);
    }
```

then i could get the right height of the bars within the height of the rectangle area

```
percentages[i] * chartHeight
```